# Unable to mount Raid 5+0 EXT4 partition

Tags: ext4, mdadm

My server has a raid 5+0 configuration which is a raid 0 device made up of 2 x raid 5 devices.

md1 is made up of md10 and md11.

```
md1 : active raid0 md10[0] md11[1]
      15627286528 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md10 : active raid5 sdh[3] sdf[0] sdg[1]
      7813774336 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md11 : active raid5 sdd[3] sda[1] sdb[4]
      7813774336 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

A few days ago I had a power cut and my one of the disks in md11 failed. I had a spare so replaced it. However when I powered up the server from replacing the disk another drive in the same array disappeared. This turned out to be a cable issue (probably knocked it when replacing the other drive). When it was reseated and turned back on the drive appeared back in the array and it was able to rebuild with the new replacement disk.

After a few hours everything was good and the array showed as healthy. However when I tried to mount the raid 0 device (md1) made up of md10 and md11 this failed with the error

```
# mount /dev/md1 md1/
mount: /storage/md1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

# fdisk -l /dev/md1
Disk /dev/md1: 14.6 TiB, 16002341404672 bytes, 31254573056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes

# fsck.ext4 /dev/md1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/md1
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

I had saved the original mkfs.ext4 command from when I built the array so I knew where the superblock backups where and tried to mount using those but they all failed

This is the original mkfs command output

```
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/md1
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Creating filesystem with 3906821632 4k blocks and 488353792 inodes
Filesystem UUID: ac6fef5c-54ea-4c79-be24-6feec0cc05fc
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632,
    2560000000, 3855122432
```

and here is what happened when I tried to mount the backups

```
# mount -o sb=32768 /dev/md1 md1/
mount: /storage/md1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

# mount -o sb=98304 /dev/md1 md1/
mount: /storage/md1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

# mount -o sb=163840 /dev/md1 md1/
mount: /storage/md1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

and so on. I tried every backup and got the same results.

```
# dumpe2fs /dev/md1 | grep -i superblock
dumpe2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
dumpe2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/md1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Is there anything else I can try to get this mounted/online again?

Thanks

### Edit 1

```
# mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md11
/dev/md11:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Apr  5 16:30:50 2023
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 7813774336 (7451.80 GiB 8001.30 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906887168 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Aug  3 23:00:46 2023
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : fileserver:11  (local to host fileserver)
              UUID : 2ccc1d61:79f0e11a:6d3bb224:797ca224
            Events : 375478

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8        0        1      active sync   /dev/sda
       3       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd


# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abd]
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2ccc1d61:79f0e11a:6d3bb224:797ca224
           Name : fileserver:11  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Wed Apr  5 16:30:50 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 7813775024 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 7813774336 (7451.80 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 88255f65:0cfbc0d7:01b3bb6b:a659a3be

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Aug  3 23:00:46 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 4fa1243c - correct
         Events : 375478

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x9
     Array UUID : 2ccc1d61:79f0e11a:6d3bb224:797ca224
           Name : fileserver:11  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Wed Apr  5 16:30:50 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 7813775024 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 7813774336 (7451.80 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0116c972:b7e63a6f:ad991903:6d0da535

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Aug  3 23:00:46 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 2e49aad - correct
         Events : 375478

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x9
     Array UUID : 2ccc1d61:79f0e11a:6d3bb224:797ca224
           Name : fileserver:11  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Wed Apr  5 16:30:50 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 7813775024 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 7813774336 (7451.80 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c244b202:6c858ef1:170354cb:6d41f5db

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Aug  3 23:00:46 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : 83ac05bd - correct
         Events : 375478

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

/dev/sdb is the replacement disk and /dev/sdd is the disk that vanished from the array temporarily.

Comment: AFAICT, the problem here is due to two drives in the same raid5 array (md11) being out of action at the same time, nothing to do with the fact that md11 was in a raid0 array with md10. It's probably unfixable except by restoring from backup (raid is not a substitute for regular backups - never has been and was never intended to be).